# Website loads slowly in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, flash, firefox

My site, http://netbiosdemo.in/web/malabarcements.com/, takes too much time to load in Mozilla Firefox.

Please help me!

Comment: Loads fine for me, what have you tried already? (if anything)

Comment: Your site is equally "slow" in all the browsers I tried (IE9, Chrome, FF). This is a poor question.

Answer (score 2):

install [the google Page speed plugin](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) in firefox and run the analisis

Answer (score 1):

Did you optimise your images/content in your Flash content (main.swf)? Half the page load is coming from there.